# Use yyyy-MM-DD format for all dates on the reputation recalc page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation-recalc

In the reputation recalc page, the list of reputation transactions are grouped by date and the date is shown in yyyy-MM-DD format, e.g.:

```
-- 2011-10-12 rep +45   = 16349     
 2   6327547 (10)
 2   6327547 (10)
-- 2011-10-13 rep +20   = 16369     
 2   5056599 (10)
-- 2011-10-14 rep +10   = 16379
```

The summary at the bottom of page shows the date in M/d/yyyy format though:

```
** rep today: 10
** rep this week (10/9/2011 - 10/15/2011): 150
** rep this month (10/1/2011 - 10/31/2011): 495
** rep this quarter (10/1/2011 - 12/31/2011): 495
** rep this year (1/1/2011 - 12/31/2011): 16004
```

Could the summary also have its dates formatted as yyyy-MM-DD?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah sure, this makes sense.  This change will go out with the next build.

Comment: I see it’s already been deployed. Thanks!